ASP.NET Detect public IP change and inform DDNS service
I'm looking to automatically handle public IP changes with my ASP.NET API server. I use a dynamic DNS service that can update the domain route according to a HTTP request sent from the server address with basic HTTP authentication (probably not too safe but it is what I'm working with). Before I used NodeRED for my backedn and had a script checking in on my public address regularily, and writing it down. And once it detected a mismatch between the stored address and queried address, it updated the DDNS using the method mentioned above.
Would regularily polling the public address of my server be the correct way of doing this in ASP.NET? Or is there an event I can subscribe to which is called in the event of a public IP change?
Has anyone done this before? If so, I'd appreciate any resources or examples regarding these implementations.
